# ggplot - Custom format for plot axis of time variable

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, data-visualization, axis-labels

How to define custom format for time variable axis in [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2)?

```
DF <- data.frame(TIME = c(350,400,250,650,500,750),
                 CATEGORY = c(1:6))


ggplot(data=DF, aes(x=CATEGORY, y=as_datetime(TIME))) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_datetime(labels = date_format("%M:%S"))
```

[image]

What I want is to remove leading zero at the minute-part. Something like this:

[image: image2]

Thanks for your time & effort!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
DF <- data.frame(TIME = c(350,400,250,650,500,750),
                 CATEGORY = c(1:6))


date_lab <- function(x) {
  paste0(minute(x), ":", format(x, "%S"))
}

ggplot(data=DF, aes(x=CATEGORY, y=as_datetime(TIME))) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_datetime(labels = date_lab)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>